# Jenkins with weblogic 12c

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, weblogic, solaris

our java EE web application is deployed on weblogic 12c, on solaris 10
however, the entire build process is very manual and no automation testing is present.
would like to find out if there any reference or books that can help us to kick start the continuous-integration process, so that build, test, deploy can be automated.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Two possible ways of doing it is via the [Jenkins Weblogic Deployer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/WebLogic+Deployer+Plugin) or by writing a few [WLST](http://www.techpaste.com/2013/05/wlst-python-script-manage-applications-life-cycle-status-check-autodeployments-weblogic/) commands and call them from the Jenkins Shell. It all depends on your proficiency with either Jenkins or Python/Jython.

There are so many solutions available, some of them right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478705/deploy-to-weblogic-using-maven-and-jenkins) on StackOverflow.